# Implicit type conversion in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function template:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(T a, T b){
         .......
}

int a = 0;
double b = 1.2;
f(a, b);
```

can a be converted to double automatically?

Comment: Why was the question downvoted? It is a legitimate question.

Comment: @SergeyA I did not downvote (reading it only now), but the question is a bit ambiguous and doesn't explain rationale at all. It doesn't explain whether `f(b, a)` should convert `double` to `int` or `int` to `double` or fail to compile. It doesn't explain whether he wants this treatment also for `short a; f(a, b)`. Neither which are the supported types of `fun`. I would have answered "*yes, use fun(double a, T b)*", but the question has no information on whether that's useless or not. Not enough reason to downvote for me. I will just move on and won't be bothered.

Answer (score 8):

> can a be converted to double automatically?

No, because it's ambiguous between `fun<int>` and `fun<double>`, when deducing the type of `T` in [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).

You could specify the template argument explicitly, to make `a` implicitly converted to `double`:

```
int a = 0;
double b = 1.2;
fun<double>(a, b);
```

or add an explicit conversion, to make the template argument deduction unambiguous:

```
int a = 0;
double b = 1.2;
fun(static_cast<double>(a), b);
```

Answer (score 0):

No it can't. There are no conversions done during the template deduction process. In this case, we deduce `T` independently from `a` and `b`, getting `int` for `a` and `double` for `b` - since we deduced `T` to be two different types, that is a deduction failure.

If you want to do conversions, the simplest thing would either be to explicitly do it yourself:

```
f(static_cast<double>(a), b);
```

Or to explicitly provide the template parameter to `f` so that no deduction happens:

```
f<double>(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is that parameter `a` be converted to type of parameter `b`, then the following template can be used instead of yours:

```
template<typename Ta, typename T>
void fun(Ta aTa, T b) {
    T& a = static_cast<T>(aTa);
    /* ... a and b have the same type T ... */
}

int a = 0;
double b = 1.2;
fun(a, b);    // works fine
```